# Running an old battery in parallel with a new one

Tags: batteries, solar-cell

I have a 100w solar panel on top of my van and with a cheapo AGM 200ah battery. After 3 years of misuse and abuse the battery is pretty worthless.

If I buy a new battery, would it be beneficial to keep the old and run it in parallel?

If so, do the batteries need to have the same amp ratings? (or is there anything else I should consider...)

(moved from http://sustainability.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others will have their own opinion but here's what I think:

Provided that your existing AGM battery is capable of keeping a charge, there isn't any downside to leaving it in the system.

However, if your existing battery has significant self-discharge, you are best to remove it.

One of the failure modes of Lead-Acid batteries is that one or more cells can develop internal short circuit paths that result in varying amounts of self-discharge current.  If your existing battery maintains its voltage above 12.5 Vdc for a week or more while sitting disconnected from anything else, it should be good.

However, if the battery voltage drops to a voltage significantly-lower than 12.5 Vdc, time to send it off to the recycle center.

The bottom line is that adding capacity to your system is a good thing.  If the existing battery is in good shape but simply has lost a portion of its capacity, you are better off having it in the system.

Comment: awesome, I've just happened to have unhooked it about a week ago.  I'll go see what the voltage is at!

Comment: still at 12.9!  Is there any easy way to measure how much capacitance it has lost?

Comment: a load test V drop / current rise is the best indicator off age, while folat voltage with a slight load ( e.g 1A) for State of Charge (SoC) for car batteries is approx 0~100% from 11.5 to 12.5V so 12.9 needs a load but possibly fully charged. V is also temperature sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider electrolyte self-leakage and internal cell shorts that can occur when voltage gets low.  Automotive batteries can suffer from this non-linear cell behavior where it seems to hold a charge and then suddenly appears dead only to be revived with a slight charge and then repeats under load. This can be monitored with a +ve and -ve indicating Ammeter rated for full scale currents in series with the old battery and load path shortest to new battery.

*I show the old battery with higher internal ESR but also it has lower Capacitance or Ah capacity. This is not mandatory, but may be useful, using a suitable DMM or analog industrial or automotive old style bi-directional ammeter or even a voltage meter with a heavy current shunt.*

[image: schematic]

This is just for checking behaviour of old battery from time to time.

If this defective non-linear condition does **not** exist yet, it may eventually, so until then may add some + net capacity.  In future beware of cell specific gravity (s.g.) matching and levels and depth of discharge and improve both. If sulphated from signs of low s.g. consider burp charging with < 50ns rise times.

Otherwise if the battery dies gracefully it will just degrade in a linear way and appears not to deliver or absorb much current due to relatively high series plate resistance and also much lower effective capacitance. When less than 10% of it's original capacity, you can consider it very inefficient.

In terms of efficiency some battery chemistries might absorb twice the charge [Ah] as they can deliver [Ah]  depending on condition and chemistry. This would require some instrument to monitor but this effect also increases with aging due to the loss in the internal series resistance \$P=I^2R\$

Comment: `This can be monitored with a bi-directional Ammeter between batteries with main feed to new battery.` could you explain how to do this this in layman's terms?

Comment: also, this may well be the more complete answer, but due to my novice level in such matters, I am unable to comprehend most of it.  Adding references to non-layman terms would improve this answer (at least for people like me)